# Unable to replace LF in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am unable to replace LF in notepad++.
Below are the steps I did

ctrl+f
Replace tab

find what      -\n
replace with   - ~

Though I have many line feeds which I can see when I go to view-show symbols, ctrl f is  not finding them, what could be the reason.

Thanks

Comment: did you try `\r\n` not only `\n`?

Answer (score 1):

When you press Ctrl + F and go to the Replace tab make sure that you have selected "Extended" in the Search Mode options.

Answer (score 0):

Depending of the source of your file there might be different encodings for a new line
[Newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

If you are working on windows most likely `\r\n` with enhanced search mode should work.